# Insert Image to a MVC Project using jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I want to insert an imege to a MVC Project, i used following code to do that,
but i want to pass that image using jquery instead of pass data using Html.BeginForm.
how can i do it,

```
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("uploadImage", "ItemMaster", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
      {
    %>
        <p><input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" size="23"/> </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload file" /></p>

        <%= Html.Hidden("hdnItemCode", null, new { style = "width:100px" })%>
    <% 
       } 
    %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a method to upload a file via jQuery, I suggest [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery).